# If $f$ is smooth and $f'$ is bounded is $f^{-1}$ $C^1$ and bounded? please check my work

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a smooth function satisfying
$$0 < C_1 \leq f'(x) \leq C_2$$
for all $x$. Am I correct that this implies the following:

1. $f^{-1}: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is $C^1$
2. $\frac{1}{C_2} \leq (f^{-1})'(x) \leq \frac{1}{C_1}$

and both of these are due to the inverse function theorem.

I am doubting because I know the inverse function theorem is about "locally" and I am asking globally.

Comment: I assume $C_1>0$? But you're not asking anything global: Both your assertions are ones that you check at (or near) one $x$ at a time.

Comment: Yes sorry $C_1$ is positive. Well I meant that the bounds need to be the independent of $x$.

Comment: Yes, I agree that the bounds hold for every $x$. But my remark stands.